# Can you import functions from an import_lib imported module using import from syntax?

Tags: python

For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
```

can be implemented:

```
import importlib
my_collection = importlib.import_module('collections')
```

Now I can get `namedtuple = my_collection.namedtuple`, but I wonder if I can do something `from something_magic(my_collection) import namedtuple`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because [`import` is a statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) whose syntax requires that the module component be

```
module ::=  (identifier ".")* identifier
```

[`identifier`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) is a literal parsed when the module is compiled, so can't be a runtime component like a function.

You could do

```
namedtuple = importlib.import_module('collections').namedtuple
```

to get a single value in the imported module which avoids explicitly creating `my_collection`, but it's basically the same thing.

And notice that `import` both imports and assigns to the importing namespace which complicates trying to import multiple values in a single statement.